# C generate random string of max length

Tags: c, string, random, ascii

I would like to generate a random string of only lower-case ASCII characters (meaning lower case letters, numbers, and other ASCII characters; just no upper-case lettesr).

The max length of the string should be 587 characters (including null terminator).

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you describe a more specific problem or add a sample code to your question ? As it is, it seems that you are asking for help before trying to solve the problem. I would carefully use the function [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) of stdlib to pick random char and i would do it 586 times in a for loop and set `string[586]='\0';`.

Comment: Do you want control characters?

Comment: yes, all ASCII characters except upper case letters

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not applied any effort to solve the problem,  stackoverflow is for answering question about compile and runtime problems, not about designing your code for you.

Comment: hmm ok I'll try francis's suggestion, thansk

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define N 588

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void gen(char *dst)
{
    int i, n;  

    srand(time(NULL));               /* init seed */
    if ((dst = malloc(N)) == NULL)   /* caller will need to free this */
        return;
    for (i = 0; i < N; )
        if ((n = rand()) < 'A' && n > 'Z')
            dst[i++] = n;
    dst[N - 1] = 0;                   /* null terminate the string */
}
```

Comment: the question states: "meaning lower case letters, numbers, and other ASCII characters; just no upper-case lettesr"   So the result needs to include everything in the range 0x00 and 0xFF, except for the range 'A'...'Z'  This answer does not fulfill the constraints of the question.   Also since it is a 'string' of 587 characters, the buffer must be 588 characters and the last byte must be a NUL byte ('\0'),  Finally, the returned value from `malloc()` needs to be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: thanks for suggestion

Comment: need to limit the values of `N` to the range 0x00...0xFF.  Also, the answer does not compile.  (the function: `time()` requires the header file: `time.h`.)  Also, when the produced value from `rand()` in the range 'A'...'Z' then nothing is set into the array `dst[]`

Comment: @user3629249 shouldn't it be from 0x00 to 0x7F as that is what is shown in http://www.asciitable.com/. Where are you getting 0xFF from?

Comment: @Kingamere,  Your right,  I was including the `extended` ascii codes 0x80 thorugh 0xFF as defined in: <http://www.asciitable.com/>

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 587 /* 587 including NULL so 0..585 and 586 is NULL */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    size_t i;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int x;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE-1; i++)
    {       
        /* Note: islower returns only a b c..x y z, isdigit 0..9 and isprint only printable characters */
        do
        {
            x = rand() % 128 + 0; /* ASCII 0 to 127 */
        }
        while (!islower(x) && !isdigit(x) && !isprint(x)); 

        buffer[i] = (char)x;
    }

    buffer[BUFFER_SIZE-1] = '\0';

    printf("%s", buffer);

    getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The above program does also print upper-case letters. Sorry. I changed the do while loop to while(1) and check x for if (x > 31 && x < 65)break;  if (x > 90 && x < 127)break;.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can do a random string with whatever characters you want. The only thing is you should put them in the function

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}
```